# Hide latex (auctex) output buffer

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex, xetex

When I compile a (Xe)LaTeX file, emacs writes the output to the LaTeX output buffer and shows it. For pure LaTeX, this buffer is hidden.

How do I hide a Latex compilation buffer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Forget it, there is this `(setq TeX-show-compilation t)` in the script I was using, so I just set it to `nil`.

Comment: Maybe just leave it... others googling it will find it. No shame in solving your own question!